# What is short code for following?

Tags: shortcode

Here is my code and I want to know what is shortcode of this? Is it `[login_form]` or do we need to add something more? With `[login_form]` there is no output as result

```
function pippin_login_form() {

if(!is_user_logged_in()) {

    global $pippin_load_css;

    // set this to true so the CSS is loaded
    $pippin_load_css = true;

    $output = pippin_login_form_fields();
} else {
    // could show some logged in user info here
    // $output = 'user info here';
}
return $output;
}
add_shortcode('login_form', 'pippin_login_form');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct, `[login_form]` is the shortcode that you should use. From the Shortcode API

> The [`add_shortcode`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) function is used to register a shortcode handler. It takes two parameters: the shortcode name (the string used in a post body), and the callback function name.

From what I can understand is that the shortcode calls a customized login form defined in a function called `pippin_login_form_fields();` There might be a couple of reasons that your shorcode does not display anything

- You are logged in. The shortcode first does a check to see if a user is logged in or not (`if(!is_user_logged_in()) {`). If a user is **not** logged in, the login form is displayed. When a user is logged in, nothing is displayed.
- There might be some type of error in the `pippin_login_form_fields();` function or it is misplaced/missing
- Some other function or filter is breaking your shortcode.

If point one is not the problem, turn on debugging in wp-config.php and check for any errors. To debug wordpress, go and check this article: [Debugging in Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)